# Connection reset by peer java.net.SocketException: Transport endpoint is not connected

Tags: java

I am using NIO threads in which ServerSocketChannel will be opened and client port will be bind.But when we tried to read the data from Socket chanel then below mention exception was displayed.It will be greatful if anyone provides the solution.

```
Connection reset by peer java.net.SocketException: Transport endpoint is not connected
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.shutdown(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.shutdownOutput(SocketChannelImpl.java:669)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketAdaptor.shutdownOutput(SocketAdaptor.java:386)
    at iyp.trncomms.ConnRecordWriter.checkShutDown(ConnRecordWriter.java:131)
    at iyp.trncomms.ConnRecordWriter.continueWriting(ConnRecordWriter.java:214)
    at iyp.trncomms.ConnRecordWriter.retry(ConnRecordWriter.java:101)
    at iyp.trncomms.ConnRecordWriter.shutDown(ConnRecordWriter.java:92)
    at iyp.trncomms.ConnRecord$WorkingState.toOnHoldState(ConnRecord.java:1224)
    at iyp.trncomms.ConnRecord$WorkingState.onInputError(ConnRecord.java:1152)
    at iyp.trncomms.ConnRecord.read(ConnRecord.java:124)
    at iyp.trncomms.NIO.run(NIO.java:137)
```

Answer (score 0):

`Connection reset by peer` is pretty explicit.  You opened the connection, but the remote side closed it before your code executed.  You need to investigate the logs on the remote system to see why the connection was closed prematurely.

Comment: @user1435862 NB it probably happened many seconds before the current shutdownOutput() method call.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be calling `shutdownOutput()` in an error case. That's not going to work: you already got an error, this will cause another one. Just close the channel.